# Identifying a musical system

Tags: history, digital-piano, synthesizer

Several years ago I was browsing about history of computers and old day computers, and downloaded various images, from Google, maybe from a blog or websites on older generation computers.

One of such image, contains a digital piano.

[image: Piano]

Now I cannot find that image throughout Google, even not by Google image search.

**Now my questions are,**

1. What software/ music system it is?
2. What file format it used?
3. Which generation of computer it worked in?

Comment: It could be just a song/melody player with a menu, a “jukebox” kind of thing. Press a key to play a tune or esc to exit. Similar music players were around for many computers. C64, Amiga, MSX, you name it. The computer in the picture is an IBM PC, but I can’t tell what the texts are, my eyes hurt when I try. The last one is ESC KEY EXIT. The menu selection keys seem to be just A B C D E F ... in alphabetical order, which would suggest that they’re just different tunes. I may be wrong.

Comment: This question might be more suitable for the Retro Computing StackExhange. Don’t know if the rules allow identification questions there, but you could try.

Comment: Please feel free to move the question.

Comment: It appears to be some version of [IBM's music.bas](https://beta-changes.fandom.com/wiki/PC-DOS:1.0/MUSIC.BAS), a program written in BASIC. Here's [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y_bqgTDtV8s) and here's [a BASIC emulation for PC](https://robhagemans.github.io/pcbasic/index.html) which looks like it might include that program or at least the landing page includes a screen shot of it. If not, it looks like this is [music.bas itself](https://github.com/jeffpar/pcjs/blob/master/apps/pcx86/1981/basic/MUSIC.BAS).

Comment: @AlwaysConfused Yeah, I only made it a comment because it looked like the thread might get closed or moved for being off topic. As for how to use PCBasic, I have no idea offhand, but it looks like you'd need to [put music.bas in your home directory](https://robhagemans.github.io/pcbasic/doc/1.2/#mounting). Otherwise, probably have a read through the rest of those [docs](https://robhagemans.github.io/pcbasic/doc/1.2/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because software and equipment/instrument identification is off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be some version of [IBM's music.bas](https://beta-changes.fandom.com/wiki/PC-DOS:1.0/MUSIC.BAS), a program written in BASIC. Here's [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y_bqgTDtV8s) and here's [a BASIC emulation for PC](https://robhagemans.github.io/pcbasic/index.html) which looks like it might include that program or at least the landing page includes a screen shot of it. If not, it looks like this is [music.bas itself](https://github.com/jeffpar/pcjs/blob/master/apps/pcx86/1981/basic/MUSIC.BAS).